# Recommended way to handle exceptions?

Tags: python, json, exception

I want to use python module `json`. In particular `loads()` function.
But I can't really find a full list of what it can throw.

Edit:
As pointed in a comment it is not required by python docs to have this info. 
What is the recommended way to handle exceptions in python? I don't want to catch all of them as as far as I know this will for instance catch KeyboardInterrupt which I don't want to happen.

Comment: It does say "If the data being deserialized is not a valid JSON document, a ValueError will be raised.", do you need more information than that?

Comment: Of course not -- it throws a `TypeError` if you pass it a non-string and a `ValueError` if you pass it a string that's not valid JSON.  Python does not require possible exceptions to be listed and Pythonistas don't expect them to be, esp. for obvious cases like these (arg of invalid type, arg with valid type but invalid value).

Comment: Please see edit. What is the recommended way to deal with exceptions in python?

Comment: Definitely try to avoid catching Exception, as this can mask all sorts of issues in your code. You want to make your except clauses as specific as possible, and wrap as little code as possible in the try block. My advice is to write unit tests on your function, trying all sorts of bad inputs to see what specific exceptions get thrown, and then catching those.

Comment: The answer may be to not deal with them. What do you plan on doing if one is thrown?

Comment: You've changed your question completely. Please edit its title and tags to reflect this -- this will make it more useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not answer your question, but what about catching all exceptions except the ones you don't need (which I think is what you want)?

```
try:
    json.loads(data)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Yo ho ho and a bottle of rum!"
```

Comment: The first problem is that I can't find the list of all exceptions given function can throw. So I can't understand what I want to catch and what I don't. This probably sounds stupid for one who has a real experience with python, buy I unfortunately don't have it.

Comment: It's really unclear to me on *what exactly do you expect* from catching specific exceptions... It's very simple function after all, it either loads the data or fails. If you really, really want to know the list of exceptions, the only thing that comes to my mind - check the json module code by yourself. But as a somewhat experienced with Python engineer I can tell you this - I think you are wasting your time on irrelevant thing, sorry.